# Does Windows remember deleted network connections?

Tags: windows-7, networking

Suppose I created a network connection "ABC" and then I deleted it. Now if I create a network connection with the same name as the previous one then after connecting windows 7 shows the name of the connected network as "ABC1". If I repeat the process I get "ABC2" and so on.

So does windows remember them somewhere may in the registry?

How can I remove this?

Comment: The simplest procedure is to search the registry for "ABC". Assuming it's a unique string it should be clear when you've found it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Control Panel (icon view) > Network and sharing center

Double Click on the Icon next to your Current network, a "Set Network Properties" window will open, then click "Merge or delete network locations"

You should be able to delete any unused locations you no longer need.

.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check in this location:

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles`.

There are a couple of other locations in that region that might be used as well.